# Apresentar conteúdo resumido no Laravel 5.1

Tags: php, laravel

Tenho um controller que realiza uma consulta paginada:

```
$noticias = Noticias::orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->paginate(4);
```

Porém, uma das colunas retornada é a **conteudo**. A coluna em questão tem muito texto, como poço fazer no Laravel para que este retorne somente um resumo contendo os 380 primeiros caracteres ou então as 200 primeiras palavras?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No `Laravel` há um recurso que nos permite retornar um valor, numa propriedade do model, como se o mesmo estivesse na tabela.

Por exemplo, se você tem o campo `conteudo` na sua tabela, você poderá fazer com que a propriedade mágica `conteudo_resumido` seja retornada, a partir desse conteúdo original.

Podemos fazer isso adicionando um método no Model, que começe com `get`, seguido do nome com StudlyCase, e em seguida com a palavra `attribute`. Ou seja:

MeuModel::getConteudoResumidoAttribute()

Exemplo:

```
class Post extends \Eloquent
{

    protected $appends = ['conteudo_resumido'];
    public function getConteudoResumidoAttribute()
    {
        return str_limit($this->getAttribute('conteudo'), 200, '...');
    }
}
```

A partir disso, podemos fazer o seguinte na chamada do nosso model `Post`:

```
@foreach($posts as $post)
   <li>{{ $post->conteudo_resumido }}
@endforeach
```

Eu usei a propriedade `appends` para determinar que o método mágico será carregado junto com o resultado trazido de uma consulta comum, pois caso necessite do mesmo no `json`, ele já será retornado automaticamente.

## Atualização

Se você estiver enfrentando problemas com tags HTML quebrada por causa do "truncate" gerado pela função `str_limit`, basta alterar o método descrito acima, colocando a função **strip_tags** antes do uso de `str_limit`.

```
str_limit(strip_tags($this->getAttribute('conteudo')), 200);
```

Assim, só serão contados os caracteres de texto, não os da tag, e você não terá problemas com tags HTML quebradas.

Answer (score -1):

Consegui fazendo assim:

```
{{ preg_replace('/(<.*?>)|(&.*?;)/', '', \Illuminate\Support\Str::words($noticia->conteudo, 70, "...")) }}
```

Com isso consigo remover as tags do html e formatações especiais, bem como limitar a um total de 70 palavras antes de inserir os três pontos, elementos estes que representam a continuidade do conteúdo.

Comment: Inserir esse tipo de lógica na view não é uma boa ideia. Caso eu precise desse mesmo resumo em outra view da aplicação preciso duplicar essa lógica enorme?

Comment: sim de fato, mas se tiver que fazer isso no controller terei que sobrescrever aquela posição do array, coreto?

Comment: Veja a resposta do @wallace. Ela já esta explicando muito bem como resolver esse tipo de problema

Comment: Se o problema eram as tags, era só falar, que eu editava as perguntas. E pra que usar preg_replace se já existe strip_tags?

Comment: Só mais uma coisa, do banco é retornado um array com o conteúdo, no seu exemplo acho que está lendo somente uma string. Para fazer o resumo de tudo terei que usar um laço certo? Ou o laravel disponibiliza algum recurso para isso?

Comment: Não entendi muito bem. Como assim o banco retorna um `array`?